# Find a context-free grammar for uc^nd^nv where the number of a's and b's in uv are equal

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I want to construct a context-free grammar for this language:

\begin{align*}
L = \{uc^nd^nv\mid \ u,v \in \{a,b\}^* \text{ and the number of a's and b's in } uv \text{ are equal}\}
\end{align*}

I know how to contruct a grammar for a language that has words with an equal number of a's and b's:
\begin{align*}
&S\to aSb \\
&S\to bSa \\
&S\to SS \\
&S\to \epsilon
\end{align*}
I also know how to construct $c^nd^n$:
\begin{align*}
&S\to cSd \\
&S\to \epsilon
\end{align*}
Could you give any hints how to combine these rules?

Comment: Observe all words of length 4 in $L$ that contain $cd$.

Comment: This in fact is a special case of the operation considered here: [Is $\{s_0ws_1:s_0s_1\in L_1,w\in L_2\}$ context free if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16048/4287).  The [solution by Yuval](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/16062/4287) there uses a construction with grammars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following operation on context-free languages. For $L\subseteq \{a,b\}^*$, we have $L_\square = \{ u\square v \mid uv\in L\}$, where $\square$ is a new symbol. Thus $L_\square$ adds a single symbol $\square$ at an arbitrary position in the strings of $L$.
That position of $\square$ can be used for the axiom to "insert" another language in your strings, by putting the axiom of this other language at that position.

How do we add a single new symbol? By tracing a path in the derivation tree, using "marked" copies of the original nonterminals, until one of these marked copies "drops" the symbol $\square$ in the string.

In your specific case that means introducing productions like $\hat S\to a\hat Sb$, $\hat S\to \hat SS$, $\hat S\to S\hat S$, $\hat S\to \square aSb$, $\hat S\to a\square Sb$ and more.